# How to use agg_func = 'All' in Python Pivot_table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have an input dataframe like given below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],'level_1': ['L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L2FR','L2Date','L2value'], 'val3':['Fasting','11/4/2005',1.33,'Random','18/1/2007',4.63,'Fasting','18/1/2017',8.63]})
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to convert my output to look like as shown below

[image]

This is what I tried based on response from SO forum

```
g = df.level_1.str[-2:]
df.pivot_table(index='person_id', columns=g, values='val3',aggfunc='first')
```

This provides only the first record of each group (or person) like shown below which is very close to my expected output.Basically I am trying to do sort of transformation/rearrange the way input data is shown

[image]

but I want to have all the records. In real data, I have more than 100k records and each person can be repeated multiple times.

When I use `g.groupby(g).cumcount()` as index, I get NA's for half of the records and I would like to avoid it. I don't know why this issue happens.

Any other way to approach this is also helpful. Can you help me get this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close to have what you want.

The trick here is to add another index to your second level like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],'level_1': ['L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L1FR','L1Date','L1value','L2FR','L2Date','L2value'], 'val3':['Fasting','11/4/2005',1.33,'Random','18/1/2007',4.63,'Fasting','18/1/2017',8.63]})
g = df.level_1.str[-2:]
# Extracting level's number
df['lvl'] = df.level_1.apply(lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))))
# Then you pivot with person_id and lvl
df = df.pivot_table(index=['person_id', 'lvl'], columns=g, values='val3', aggfunc='first')
```

Output should be :

```
            level_1     FR          te          ue
person_id   lvl             
        1   1       Fasting     11/4/2005   1.33
        2   1           Random      18/1/2007   4.63
            2           Fasting     18/1/2017   8.63
```

Then if you reset the level 1 index like this :

`df.reset_index(level=1).drop("lvl", axis=1)`

The output is :

```
level_1     FR          te          ue
person_id           
1           Fasting     11/4/2005   1.33
2           Random      18/1/2007   4.63
2           Fasting     18/1/2017   8.63
```

And there you go !

Comment: Actually the levels might go up 150 like L1, L2, L3, ...L150. In that case will df.level_1.str[0:n] option help to create uniform levels for other persons as well?

Comment: I mean person_id = 1 can have 1 level, whereas person_id = 2 can have 2 levels, whereas person_id = 10 can have 15 levels

Comment: Oh I see ! Then you should consider extracting numbers from the level_1 column then assign the value in `lvl`column. Updating my answer

Comment: Just sharing info that last few chars of all columns remain the same. I mean L1FR, L2FR, L3FR, L1Date, L2DATE,l3DATE, L1Value,L2Value,L3Value...Here last 2-3 chars is same if that can be any helpful for the solution

Comment: trying your answer

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'filter' and 'filter'". A filter object is created under 'lvl' column of dataframe and when I try to pivot it, it throws the above error..

Comment: Whoops my bad, must add a `"".join()` befor the filter, editing my post.

Comment: Does it make any difference if we have levels as digits or as str[0:2],it would still be the same. Am I right?

Comment: Yes basicaly it's the same, you just need to add an index to avoid aggragation while pivoting your dataframe

Comment: Thanks for your help. Much appreciated

Comment: One quick question. Why is `agg_func` always a mandatory parameter? If i ignore the `agg_func` in the sample above, I get an error message that `no numeric types to aggregate`